# DRF - Unable to log in with provided credentials

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I tried to get a token from django rest framework.

```
bigissue@vmi995554:/opt/ftusbrdp/sbin$ http POST http://172.18.0.1:7000/api-token-auth/ username='nicola' password="Password12345"
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 68
Content-Type: application/json
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2022 14:19:40 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.9.15
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY

{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
    ]
}
```

I have create superuser and also a normal user from admin web gui. All users are active. What I'm missing? Here down is my configuration.
I have import module app like rest_framework and rest_framework.authtoken, I set REST_FRAMEWORK variable for token use. Then I call views.obtain_auth_token methods to get string token.

The settings.py file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'appjud',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken'
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
               'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':(
                'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),

}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbjud',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'Password19',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}
```

The router.py file

```
from appjud.viewsets import userviewsets
from rest_framework import routers
 
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('user', userviewsets, basename ='user_api')
```

The serialiers.py file

```
class userSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields =  '__all__'
```

The viewsets.py file

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import userSerializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 
 
class userviewsets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = userSerializers
```

The urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from unimiproject.router import router
from rest_framework.authtoken import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    re_path(r"^appjud/",include("appjud.urls")),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token, name='api-token-auth'),

]
```

Comment: Well, the request is reaching the endpoint. It looks like, either the request data username or password is not being passed properly or simply you have written the wrong values.

Comment: I have changed password from "Password$12345" to "pagus1988" without special char "$" and it works! There is something incorrect with special chars like "$". Thank you for your support.